# NavigationService not working in Silverlight

Tags: wcf, silverlight, out-of-browser, navigationservice

I'm trying to change the loaded page in my OOB Silverlight application.
I've added reference to Navigation assembly, but still, when I tipe NavigationService. and ctrl+space, I can't see any of the methods or properties that i should. Here's that part of code:

```
void client_LoginCompleted(object sender, LoginCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Result)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Welcome {0}", user.Text), "Success!", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        NavigationService.Navigate(someUri);
    }
}
```

The problem occurs on the line where I call the NavigationService. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to this little hick-up. Considering I'm new in Silverlight, i didn't even think there's more work than that piece of code in my question. I have resolved my problem like shown in this video: http://www.silverlight.net/learn/graphics/windows,-screens,-navigation/navigation-framework